# Not able to send data as json in retrofit 2 in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am not able to send data as row json format in retrofit.

I migrated retrofit 1.9 to 2. In retrfit 1.9 i am able to send raw json using HashMap but in retrofit 2 I am using HashMap to but i was not able to send data as json. 
So i am using pojo instead.

api generate log of Trying to get property of non-object so i am not able to pass data in row json.

I just saw my server detail in error_log that my request automatically converted to GET. I passed data in POST using retrofit2,retrofit 1.9, volly any Asynctask too. I don't know why my server is took it as GET.
From the postman it's worked fine.

Any help would be useful to me. 
Thanks

here is my code

my pojo class for request

```
  public class RegisterdUserData {

@SerializedName("userEmail")
@Expose
private String userEmail;
@SerializedName("userName")
@Expose
private String userName;
@SerializedName("firstName")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("userPassword")
@Expose
private String userPassword;
@SerializedName("userRole")
@Expose
private String userRole;

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}

public String getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
```

Request

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/api/CreateUser.php")
Call<AppUserData> CreateUser(@Body RegisterdUserData registerdUserData);
```

My call

```
 private void CreateUser(String userEmail, String firstName, String lasName, String userName, String userPassword, String userRole) {

    RegisterdUserData registerdUserData = new RegisterdUserData();
    registerdUserData.setFirstName(firstName);
    registerdUserData.setLastName(lasName);
    registerdUserData.setUserEmail(userEmail);
    registerdUserData.setUserName(userName);
    registerdUserData.setUserPassword(userPassword);
    registerdUserData.setUserRole(userRole);
    util.http.CreateUser(registerdUserData).enqueue(new Callback<AppUserData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AppUserData> call, Response<AppUserData> response) {
            util.log(TAG, "" + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AppUserData> call, Throwable t) {
            util.log(TAG, "" + t);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try changing `@POST("/api/CreateUser.php")` to `@POST("api/CreateUser.php")`

Comment: It was not helpful. @AshutoshSagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with www. If i am removing it then it works fine. I don't know why. but it helped me.
Thanks for your response @Manikanta @AshutoshSaga

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to send data in the form of `Map<String,Object>`

In your case:

```
Map<String,Object> requestBody = new HashMap()<>;
requestBody.put("userInfo", registerdUserData);
```

And your request should be:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/api/CreateUser.php")
Call<AppUserData> CreateUser(@Body Map<String,Object> registerdUserData);
```

Also cross check on how the retrofit object is being built(in my case it is jackson).

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Do comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: same error.  i am using gson for addConverterFactory. did it matter for this error?

Comment: Just Giving it a try with JacksonConvertorFactory. and Map<> as a request body worth it!!.